# Algebraic closure and GIT

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fields, geometric-invariant-theory

Does one need to work over an algebraic closed field in ordre to construct GIT quotients à la Mumford?
If yes, why?

Comment: Have you looked in Mumford's book?

Comment: $X = {\rm Proj}\ R$, $X//G := {\rm Proj}\ R^G$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey MBeasy,

you can construct the quotients over an arbitrary "not necessarily algebraically closed field", as Mumford states at the beginning of chapter 1.

Greetings

Daniel